# Codeigniter redirect (or forward to another controller equivalent) in CMD mode

Tags: codeigniter, redirect, cron

```
Redirect ('controller_name');
```

works in http mode but NOT in cmd mode.

How can I forward to another controller in CMD mode in Codeigniter?

```
I'm trying to achieve the following.
Controller A forward to Controller B (one of many subclasses of A decided upon what Model A returns in that time) in cron jobs.
```

Answer (score 1):

`Redirect` simply does a `header('location: controller_name');` which can't be done in CLI mode.

If you are trying to load another controller and execute it, you are best off looking at the HMVC (http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Modular_Extensions_-_HMVC/) method as you can do:

```
modules::run('controller_b/action/param');
```

instead of

```
redirect('controller_b/action/param');
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: i've read quite a bit but it looks way too complex for a simple task, but thanks. I will try it later if there's no other way.

Comment: After installing the HMVC code, doing what you need is extremely simple, however I understand it wouldn't follow the same "flow" as a normal web page would.